# Elastic Search sort by distance on a sub tag

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am just starting with ElasticSearch, and have managed to do basic queries, etc, but right now I have a data mapping like so:

```
merchant: {
  properties: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer'
    },
    name: {
      type: 'text'
    },
    logo: {
      type: 'boolean'
    }
  }
},
store: {
  properties: {
    location: {
      type: 'geo_point'
    },
    category: {
      type: 'integer'
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to sort the results based on the distance from the docs [Distance Sort Example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/decay-functions.html). Now I am unable to figure out how to make it work with the location field under store. Using `store.location` gives an error like so:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "unknown field [store.location]",
        "line" : 1,
        "col" : 0
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "merchants",
        "node" : "9t4Z6koOTe2rWZmNcwYNNQ",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "parsing_exception",
          "reason" : "unknown field [store.location]",
          "line" : 1,
          "col" : 0
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I am unable to find what would make this work with `store.location`

```
{
    "merchants" => {
        "mappings" => {
            "store" => {
                "properties" => {
                    "category" => {
                        "type" => "integer"
                    }, "location" => {
                        "type" => "geo_point"
                    }
                }
            }, "merchant" => {
                "properties" => {
                    "id" => {
                        "type" => "integer"
                    }, "logo" => {
                        "type" => "boolean"
                    }, "name" => {
                        "type" => "text"
                    }
                }
            }, "offer" => {
                "properties" => {
                    "description" => {
                        "type" => "text"
                    }, "expiresAt" => {
                        "type" => "integer"
                    }, "id" => {
                        "type" => "integer"
                    }, "intro" => {
                        "type" => "text"
                    }, "title" => {
                        "type" => "text"
                    }, "top" => {
                        "type" => "integer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide the exact response from the get mapping API for this particular index. Is the above mapping really applied is the question, as it does not look like it. Are you only querying indices that have the above mentioned field or are you accidentally trying to query all indices or something like that?

Comment: @alr here's the response I got `{"acknowledged": true, "shards_acknowledged": true}`. I am querying on the same index(created as the name merchants, and query url being /merchants/_search)

Comment: @alr, sorry, pasted something wrong above. Added the response in the question itself.